# C++ Steam ID authentication via Game Client

Tags: c++, encryption, server

So basically, I have a game client and a game server.

A game clients connects to the server, sending its Steam ID to the server.

The game server sees that this is a new Steam ID, so it makes a row and adds the players info (ip, name, steam id) to the players table.

The game server is able to ban players by their Steam ID. So the next time a player connects, the server checks their Steam ID with one in the table. If it found one and that Steam ID is banned, disconnect the player.

The only way for the game server to know the Steam ID of a player is to have the player use the Steam API and retrieve his Steam ID via the session made with Steam and then send it as a string to the Game Server.

However, I have a problem. Just sending the Steam ID alone is not secure as a player who has been banned can simply modify the packet going out to the server to another Steam ID, thus "unbanning" them.

**What is a secure way I can send something like a Steam ID string to my game server, and having the server tell whether or not it was modified or if it was sent as it was intended from the game client?**

My game client uses **Game Maker: Studio** and my game server uses **C++**.

*PS: I made a question before but I wasn't descriptive enough so I made a new one.*

Comment: (I remember your last question.) Really, you need to post some code otherwise this belongs on one of the other stack networks.

Comment: What code? All I'm doing right now is literally just sending a string (Steam ID) to the server, and the server receives the string and assumes it's unmodified.

Comment: stackoverflow Is meant for programming questions/ answers. I believe  you should ask this on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exacts of what you are asking, here's a psuedo bit of thinking...

I would have the client first do a 'handshake' with the server where it receives the 'salt-of-the-day' (a 32-byte hash that is generated daily).  The Client would then take that salt, encrypt the steam_id that is on the client, and transmit that data do the server, where the server would then de-crypt it and verify it against your plaintext database.

But remember, for as much encrypting that you actually do, someone somewhere will eventually crack your code and be able to thwart your best security defenses.

**EDIT**

Here's a [LINK W/ SOURCE CODE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23769/Simple-String-Encryption-and-Decryption-with-Sourc) that describes a simple encryption for strings.  Now the code is in C#, but I'm sure it can be studied to convert it to C++ just as easily.

Comment: Thanks you! Do you have a recommended salt-method?

Comment: without going into specifics, as you can find your own real method--try creating a salt that includes the current date, some randomly generated hexadecimal number (32-bytes would be best), then you can do a md5/sha1/combo-there-of hash to be stored in your database.  Glad I could help, but as it was commented above, without specific code, stackoverflow might not have been the best place. ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer above to reflect _**one**_ way you could use basic encryption between server and client.

Answer (score 0):

The way integrity of data is checked is usually by using one-way hash functions. These are functions that given some input (data, in this case a steam ID) produces a hash value. Given this output it is nearly impossible to decrypt it back to the original message. This is the way passwords are encoded. The password is encrypted using a one way hash function. Afterwards if for example an attacker gets this encrypted password, he can't decrypt it to the real password. However if the user wants to connect you can use the hash function and check if the result is the same as what is stored in the database.

So with this you can achieve integrity of data, given the data you can pass it through the one-way hash function and send the data together with the hash value. On the other side when the data is received you can compute the hash value using the same hash function. If it is the same as the hash value received with the message, you can be sure nobody changed the message on it's way. This is how data integrity is achieved in for example distributed systems.

Notice that it is nearly impossible to come up with a value that hashes to the same value (because one-way hash functions have to be very sensitive to it's input, changing just one bit should change the output totally).

I couldn't figure out from your question but if in your case it's the user himself who is sending you his steam ID, you can't be sure it wasn't changed. Because he will compute the hash value himself...

You can find a good explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).